# Clicking on a grid - UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I am develop an new UWP app, and I have a grid:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="*" />
       <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

My table has 2 rows and 2 columns. In each row and column I have an image, and some textblocks. I would like that when click in each cell (for example when click on line 0 and column 0 of my grid) go to a XAML page.

How do I make my table cells clickable?

Comment: You can also but stackpanel on each grid row and column so you can but your textblock and image on stackpanel and use tapped event on stack pannel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Grid itself is just a layout control and on itself it will not tell you which cell was clicked, you can only know it's area was clicked.

What you can do is to put some controls in the cells (in this case ideally a `Button`) and set a `Click` or `Tapped` of those:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="*" />
           <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                   Click="FirstCellClicked" />
    ...
 </Grid>
```

If you want something more subtle, you could use a `Rectangle` instead of the `Button`, set its `Fill` to `Transparent` (so that it captures user input) and then use it's `Tapped` event to handle the click.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="*" />
           <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                   Tapped="FirstCellTapped" />
    ...
 </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not what I want. What I want is that the whole cell is clickable. That is, I can click anywhere on the cell and go to a XAML page that I want.

Comment: Yes, you can do that with a `Rectangle` that has `Horizontal` and `VerticalAlignment` set to `Stretch`

Comment: The `Rectangle` can be behind all other content in the cell. You can also put another `Grid` in place of `Rectangle` to be able to layout inside the cell.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I want. I'm just having a little problem, `Tapped` is not working, it does not navigate to any XAML page. I'm using this: `this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(XamlPage));`

Comment: Make sure you set the Fill of the Rectangle to Transparent. If it is not set, it doesn't capture the user input.

Comment: Thank you. It works more or less. Not always clicking the cell navigates to another XAML page

Comment: You can use a different event like `PointerPressed` which works more reliably than `Tapped`

Comment: If that solved your question, please mark the answer, so that the question is resolved :-) . Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Put a button in each cell of the grid and set the content of the button to an image.  With the button you can use the click event to navigate to another xaml page.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
     <Image x:Key="MyImage" Source.../>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Button Content="{StaticResource MyImage}" />
```

With a textblock you could do something like this.

```
<Button>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>My text here</TextBlock>
    <Image Source="some.jpg" Stretch="None" />
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not what I want. What I want is that the whole cell is clickable

Comment: When you set the horizontal and vertical content alignment, it fills the whole cell.  i.e it makes the whole cell clickable